# How to replace value in URL in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, url, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace `5e0361f5af70f400441148` in `https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/5e0361f5af70f40044112148/dbt` to `id`. In the end should receive 
`https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/id/dbt`

I use `regexp_replace('https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/5e0361f5af70f400441148/dbt','[[:digit:]]','','g')` but i do not know how to replace alphabet also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that Id is always using lowercase a-f, the following will do:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/5e0361f5af70f400441148/dbt' , '/[0-9,a-f]+/','/id/');
```

Otherwise add the A-F range: `'/[0-9,a-f,A-F]+/'`

This will break if other parts of your url contain `[0-9,a-f]` characters only.

If your input contains more than one id, add a `'g'` modifier like so:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/5e0361f5af70f40044112148/dbt/5e036445af70f40b1012b48f/top-chart', '/[0-9,a-f]+/','/id/','g');
```

Comment: what this part \/ do? in case i have 2 id's https://place.mycompany.com/analyst/5e0361f5af70f40044112148/dbt/5e036445af70f40b1012b48f/top-chart

Comment: Actually the escaping is not needed, I'll change it.

Comment: Added `'g'` modifier in case you have more than one id in your input.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! just found:  'g' instructs the function to remove all, not just the first one.